# AWS Availability Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, high-availability, devops

I am trawling through the array of AWS services but cannot see the wood from the trees. What I would like to do is provide my own health check script, that I would deploy on my VM and that I can call over HTTP for example. Based on the result of that script (x failures for example), i would like to trigger the termination of this VM and perhaps let auto scaling group replace it or perhaps trigger direct API call to instantiate a replacement VM.

What is the standard/recommended AWS mechanism for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Classic Loadbalancer / Application Loadbalancer can perform Health checks via http. You can configure a auto scaling group to use the healthcheck of the load balancer. So if the healthcheck no longer is healthy the instance will be replaced by the auto scaling group.

The only thing that you need to provide is a http endpoint that returns 200 if the app is healthy. Or in the case of the new Application Loadbalancer you can also return something else than 200 and configure the healthcheck accordingly.